# how to store the value from html into another variable in directive

Tags: angularjs

below is my sample.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {

      scope: {
          griddata:'=',
        },


    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>',
    compile: function(cElem, cAttrs) {
          return {

            post:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { 

                scope.variable = iAttrs.griddata;
                alert("inside compile"+scope.variable );
            }};
            } };
});
```

below is my sample.html

```
<hello-world griddata = "mydata">
```

I am trying to assign the value of griddata i.e mydata to another variable in compile function of this directive how to do this I have to get this alert as `inside copile mydata` , so that I can send this value to another controller.please suggest me how to do this.working fine inside pre function bt getting TypeError: iAttrs is undefined error in post function of compile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try   scope.variable = iAttrs.griddata ;  instead of scope.variable = 'griddata';

Comment: Yes Its working inside compile function bt my original requirement is to get that value in a timeout function when I give like this $timeout(function(iAttrs){ scope.variable = iAttrs.griddata ; alert("griddata is..."+scope.variable);},500); Its showing me an error saying Error: iAttrs is undefined.